# Align Tikz-Pie-Chart caption with chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I am trying to align the caption of a pie-chart that I create with the `tikz` `pgf-pie` package.
The goal is to have multiple pie-charts next to each other in one line.

So far I tried creating a `figure` environment, putting the `tikz` environment containing the `pie-chart` in the figure and adding a caption.
However the caption is not centralized beneath the pie-chart but weirdly central to the page.
If I use the `\centering` command in the `figure` environment, than the whole figure/pie-chart is centralized to the page and not aligned to the left.

**So, how do I align the caption central to the pie-chart and not to the page?**

---

**How it should look**

[image: Pie Chart correct]

**How it looks**

[image: Pie Chart wrong]

My minimal working example looks like so:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    %\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} % Tikz environment
        \pie[rotate=270, radius=2]
        {46/Germany, 21/Austria and Switzerland, 25/Europe, 8/Asia and America}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Revenue by Geographic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want, here are two solutions:

- using minipages
- using subfigures

So

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}] % Tikz environment
        \pie[rotate=270, radius=2]
        {46/Germany, 21/Austria and Switzerland, 25/Europe, 8/Asia and America}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{Revenue by Geographic}
\end{minipage}}
\hfill
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}] % Tikz environment
\pie[rotate=270, radius=2]
{46/Germany, 21/Austria and Switzerland, 25/Europe, 8/Asia and America}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Revenue by Geographic}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \fbox{\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}] % Tikz environment
        \pie[rotate=270, radius=2]
        {46/Germany, 21/Austria and Switzerland, 25/Europe, 8/Asia and America}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}}%
    \hfill
    \fbox{\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}] % Tikz environment
        \pie[rotate=270, radius=2]
        {46/Germany, 21/Austria and Switzerland, 25/Europe, 8/Asia and America}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}}
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you give me a hint when to use what? Are there preferences for using subfigures over minipages and vice versa?

Comment: As you wrote “The goal is to have multiple pie-charts next to each other in one line.“, maybe I'll use subfigures, instead of having many figures. I imagine it depends what your pie-charts represent.

Comment: They should appear in one line, however are not correlated. However, one other question. How does the "[scale=.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}]" affect the tikzenvironment?

Comment: The first `scale` reduce everything but the texts, so the need for the second one.

Answer (score 3):

The center of the pie chart pie (0,0) is often not the center of the bounding box.  If you want to align the caption with the pie, you will need to make the bounding box symmetrical about the origin.

I added an overlay to show the center accurately.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} % Tikz environment
        \pie[rotate=270, radius=2]
        {46/Germany, 21/Austria and Switzerland, 25/Europe, 8/Asia and America}
        \path (current bounding box.south west);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\xleft}{\ybottom}%
        \path (current bounding box.north east);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\xright}{\ytop}%
        \path (-\xleft,-\ybottom) (-\xright,-\ytop);% symmetrize bounding box
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Revenue by Geographic}
    \smash{\rule{0.5pt}{2in}}% overlay line through center (remove)
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]