# problem with subfigure exactly below the figure

Tags: floats, elsarticle

I have a problem with subcaption. It does not appear exactly below my figure in center like photo attached. Would you please check it?

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfigure}



\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{main1.pdf}\label{fig:f1}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{main2.pdf}\label{fig:f2}}
  \caption{Replacement material type variation (a) individual (b) combined}
  \label{PIE}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please format your LaTeX code correctly and provide a minimal but complete code. Moreover, CTAN indicates that `subfigure` is an obsolete package, replaced by `subcaption`.

Comment: Don't load both `subfig` and `subcaption`. Choose one or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is it, say, about the labels `(a)` and `(b)` not being centered below the pie-charts?

Comment: `subfig` is also marked as deprecated on CTAN. Both it and `subfigure` are replaced by `subcaption`.

Comment: The legend makes your images lopsided, so the center of the image is not the center of the pie.  If the pie charts were create using standalone, there are ways to balance the sides.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577687/align-tikz-pie-chart-caption-with-chart/577750?r=SearchResults&s=1|84.1274#577750

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example with current package `subcaption`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{subrefformat=brace}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{main1.pdf}
    \caption{\label{fig:f1}}
    \end{subfigure}
\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{main2.pdf}
    \caption{\label{fig:f2}}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{\label{PIE}Replacement material type variation \subref{fig:f1} individual, \subref{fig:f2} combined.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Your document example is not complete, consequently it is not compilable (missed are `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, used are figures which we haven't).
- Package `subcaption is loaded twice (ones is sufficient ;-) ).
- Packages `subfig` and `subcaptions` are not compatible. Use just one of them!
- Package `subcaption` version 1.3 support `\subfloat` too.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\textwidth}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\label{fig:f1}} %   {main1.pdf}
    \hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\label{fig:f2}} %   {main2.pdf}
%
\caption{Replacement material type variation (a) individual (b) combined}
  \label{PIE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not loading both `subfig` and `subcaption`, adding `\begin{document}`, The example code does show the captions centered on the fiures

```tex
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{array} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] \centering \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:f1}} \hfill \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:f2}} \caption{Replacement material type variation (a) individual (b) combined} \label{PIE} \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]